# Get the last 2 run times of Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am using a timer-triggered Azure Function to move data from a database every X minutes. To do so I'd like to access the last two run time and use it to scope my database query, such that I get all the logs from SecondLastRunTime to LastRunTime. Assuming I run my timer every X minutes, this should give me all the logs.

How can I access this info? Also, any recommendations for handling timer failures?

Answer (score 0):

These details aren't automatically available from the TimerTrigger.

However, you should be able to use an output binding write out these details to Table storage or DocDb or (any other storage type) whenever the function runs. You can then use an input binding to auto-load the data whenever the trigger fires.

Here's a link to the Table input/output bindings that may be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table

One approach to TimerTrigger failures is to have the triggered function do very little work and, instead, write some context to a Queue message (maybe the timestamp of when it fired?). Then, a separate QueueTrigger function can act on that message. The nice thing about this is that the QueueTrigger performs auto-retries (up to 5 times by default) and stores anything that fails in a 'poison' queue for you to evaluate later. It also helps to write your functions in a way that (a) they're idempotent: if you run it multiple times in a row, you get the same outcome and (b) the function can handle a scenario where a previous run failed: that may mean cleaning up the failed processing or just ignoring it so that it can be cleaned up manually later.